# How to set properties dynamically depending on environment?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio for developing app. I want to load one property file depending on environment..
For example, if I pass the filename like this:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -PextPropFile="prod.properties"
```

then I want load properties from that file in java class..

How to do this?

Comment: I tried iam able to get that property in build.gradle...but from the build.gradle how can pass it to my custom java class.?